# Variable definitions in nested for loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

Some static languages like Java seem to have very special rules for variables defined in the first argument of a for loop. They are accessible only by the given loop, which makes them behave pretty much like javascript functions' local variables and arguments. I mean stuff like this:

```
class ForVariable {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i != 0; i++) {}
    System.out.println(i); // Throws an Exception
  }
}
```

Javascript doesn't behave like  that, which makes nesting loops quite a messy business. My question is: **Is it valid to declare variables in the subsequent loops via the var keyword**? In other words - which of the following examples is valid?

```
for(var i = 0, j; i < 5; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) <do some stuff>;
}
```

OR

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) <do some stuff>;
}
```

Clearly it is wrong to declare a variable several times, which would make the 2nd example a no-go, but given the fact that the 1st example is the way loops nesting is done in most languages I know, I'm rather hesitant to declare the winner.

Comment: There is no concept of block scope in javascript only function scope, using the `var` keyword in loop declarations (or inside `if`s) have the same effect as declaring the with the `var` keyword in the start of the function. (unlike Java, C and others)

Comment: Right. But that would mean that those `var`s in the nested loops would be executed several times, which doesn't seem too valid a solution, or?

Comment: There is no actual problem using `var` many times(but sometimes maybe a logic error). In the case(loop bocks) the variables will just be accessible outside the loop blocks as well, and you may run into weird problems if you expect block scope in case you use the same name for the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not *wrong* to declare a variable several times. For instance there is really no problem with:

```
var i = 0;
var i = 1;
```

That's valid JavaScript. Good tools like the Closure Compiler will generate a warning though because you typically don't intend to do that.

That being said, even the Closure Compiler won't generate a warning for your example #2. It's just common convention in JS even if you are technically re-declaring.

Either of your two examples is *fine* but the second one is a little more sensible to parse. I wouldn't worry about it either way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't it however bad practice to declare the same variable multiple times in the same scope? `var`s and `function`s are first-class citizens in javascript, which could make the preparation of a scope slightly slower, could it not?

Comment: well, the compiler will actually only declare it once at the start of the function, so it won't be any slower at runtime. Look up "JavaScript hoisting" for why that is.

Answer (score 4):

Those are both valid. [Function scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) vs block scoped. Basically both loops in JavaScript become:

```
function a () {
    var i, j;
    for(i = 0, j; i < 5; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) <do some stuff>;
    }
}
```

because the `var` declarations are [**hoisted**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Variable_Scope) to the top

Comment: Well, `a = 1;` executed in the global scope will have the same effect as `var a = 1; var a = 1; var a = 1;`. That, however, doesn't make either of them a valid variable definition, which is what my question has been about.

Comment: I told you they are both valid friend, but I tried to explain why they are both valid due to hoisting and scope in JavaScript

Comment: Right, thanks for the details provided I can see your point. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be using the `var` keyword, but rather function arguments, because javascript is not block-scoped. For example:

```
[100,200,300].forEach(function (x,i) {
    [10,20,30].forEach(function (y,j) {
        console.log('loop variables, indices '+[i,j]+' have values: '+[x,y]);
    });
})
```

or

```
[100,200,300].map(function (x,i) {
    return [10,20,30].map(function (y,j) {
        return x+y;
    });
})

// result: [[110,120,130],[210,220,230],[310,320,330]]
```

Comment: Right, as I said it is a messy business, which makes ECMA5 methods a bliss. However, that doesn't really answer my question. :-)

Comment: @Witiko: Ah, oops, a developer who actually knows things. =) Sorry, I thought you were merely asking "how do you make a nested for-loop work?" not an in-depth syntactic question. Hopefully someone else can shed light, or you can look at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm Good luck. (Might as well leave answer here for reference for others.)